# What keeps our organs in place?

Tags: blood, internal-organs

Do they float iniside our "blood blob inside our body" or they are connected to our muscles ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They’re fastened together by blood vessels, nerves and most importantly, connective tissue, muscles and bones.

[image]

<sup>Image Source: anatomyorgan.com</sup>

[image]

<sup>Image Source: [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/abdominal-muscle)</sup>

The same holds true for other organs in the body, although the skin and the brain are slightly different cases.

The brain does float around, albeit in the cerebrospinal fluid, and very rapid movements (like hitting the head) can cause the brain to clash against the skull, causing a [concussion](https://www.webmd.com/brain/tc/traumatic-brain-injury-concussion-overview).

[image]

<sup>Image Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/1317_CFS_Circulation.jpg)</sup>

The skin is a muscle itself, connected to other muscles and tendons and is also supported by the skeleton.

Comment: Also: Why people loves to diss (Downvote) every single question they see here ? Why my totally intellectual question is dissed ?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe it was because it seems like a silly question (the human blood is contained in arteries and veins which are surrounded by muscle tissue, but the question what really does hold organs in place is interesting nonetheless. // Some questions are off-topic, and our policy is to downvote and close them. Also, some answers don’t provide references or are straight out wrong, so that’s why you might encounter more downvotes.

Comment: @JonathanIrons most likely for lack of research. This is something easily found out, and trivial questions on every site tend to get downvoted. As one of the CM's puts it, "we are not trying to replicate google."

Comment: Also, Narusan, you managed to leave out the majority of the organs in the body. You missed the entire lower abdomen.

Comment: @JohnP Updated it. With hips & spine, I meant the *pars lumbalis* and *cingulum membri pelvini* provide support as bones, as well as the many muscles around / included in said organs. I tried not to go into too much detail since the OP didn’t seem to versed in medical slang etc. Also, clearing up the misconception that we had blood blobs inside our body seemed more important to me. // Also, I‘m not a native speaker and translating medical terminology is a pain, so sorry if „hips and spine“ was too broad.